# When to use define macro vs generate

Tags: macros, system-verilog

What are the guidelines for choosing generate statements over `define macros and vice versa in Systemverilog?

For example, if I want to conditionally instantiate either module1 or module2, it seems I can either do

```
`ifdef COND1
module1 ();
`else
module2 ();
```

or

```
generate
if (COND1) begin
module1 ();
end else begin
module2();
end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People will have differing opinions, but one big difference between the two is that generates allow different instances to be configured differently, but macros do not. This is because generates are evaluated at elaboration, rather than at compile time.

For example, if we have a module:

```
module ahwoogaa #(bit COND1) ();

  generate
    if (COND1) begin
      module1 ();
    end else begin
      module2();
    end
  endgenerate

endmodule
```

I can instantiate that twice with COND1 like so:

```
module neeenaaaw();

  ahwoogaa #(1'b0) alarm1();
  ahwoogaa #(1'b1) alarm2();

endmodule
```

With a `define` you have to have a single value of `COND1` for all instances, as you set the value once when you compile the module.

Personally I say go for generates whenever you can.

Answer (score 2):

`` `ifdef `` can be used inside port lists:

```
module music
  output [31:0] left,
`ifdef STEREO
  output [31:0] right,
`enfif
...
```

Generate allows loops, instantiate X times

```
genvar inst;
generate 
  for (inst=0; inst<3; inst=inst+1) begin : gen_block
   sub_module instancex( .clk, .din(din[inst]), .dout(dout[inst]) );
  end
endgenerate
```

NB: this introduces an extra level of hierarchy (gen_block).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the questions concerns conditional instantiation only.

We had similar dilemma some time ago, when our project, initially developed in order to be integrated into specific platform, had to be adapted for additional platform. We wanted to use IFDEFs/Generates for differentiating a single source code.

In my opinion:

1) IFDEFs look much simpler than Generates (and they really are), but they are dangerous. Use them only when you're completely sure that your conditional instantiation will be exclusive (see the answer by Paul S), you can't achieve the same functionality with generates, and you're completely sure you need this conditional instantiation. The usual place to use IFDEFs is in top hierarchies.

**EDIT:** there is [another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254884/how-to-bind-an-interface-to-multiple-ports-without-duplicating-code/17262782?noredirect=1#comment25022429_17262782) which is an example of struggling of verification engineer due to abuse of `ifdefs by some designer.

2) After I warned you with the 1 above, I can tell that IFDEFs has a huge advantage (as a result of them being pre-processed): you can conditionally instantiate nets, parameters and ports with IFDEFs. Compare the following use of IFDEF:

```
module module1 (
input in1,

output logic out1

`ifdef COND
, output logic out2
`endif 
);


assign out1 = in1;   

`ifdef COND
submodule submodule1(.in(in1), .out(out2));
`else

endmodule
```

and generate:

```
module module1 (
input in1,

output logic out1,

output logic out2
);

assign out1 = in1;  

generate if (COND)
submodule submodule1(.in(in1), .out(out2));
else
assign out2 = in1;
endgenerate

endmodule
```

In the above (very simple) example, when COND is not true and you use IFDEF, you may not worry about driving "out2" - this port will not be present. As a downside, you'll have to use the same IFDEF when instantiating "module1". 
The advantage of IFDEF may not be obvious in this example, but imagine that you have 100 ports (or nets) which connect some sub-module. If the sub module is not instantiated you'll have all these ports tied to some value when using Generate, but you can remove them with IFDEFs.

3) As Morgan mentioned, Generate introduces one extra level of hierarchy. While it is slightly irritating to see this in design navigator, it becomes a real pain in the @ss when you want to insert generates into existing code and there are tools which make use of paths to modules - you have to find all these tools and change hierarchy there.

4) I heard an opinion that IFDEFs "age" badly. It means that maintaining your code will be more difficult if you use IFDEFs over Generates.

Summary: after trying some time to differentiate our design with IFDEFs and Generates, we realized that it is not practical. Now we maintain two source codes in parallel - one for each platform. Use IFDEFs in top modules to remove/switch between modules and remove unnecessary ports and parameters. Use Generates when you want to use the same modules in slightly different parametrization. Do not use these constructs to apply major changes to your design.