# How to bind an interface to multiple ports without duplicating code?

Tags: interface, system-verilog

In this example, how do I create a single interface bind statement that can be reused for both ports of the module:

```
module adderSubtractor2(
  input            clk,
  input [7:0]      a0,
  input [7:0]      b0,
  input            doAdd0, // if this is 1, add; else subtract
  output reg [8:0] result0
`ifdef HAS_UNIT_2
  ,
  input [7:0]      a1,
  input [7:0]      b1,
  input            doAdd1, // if this is 1, add; else subtract
  output reg [8:0] result1  
`endif
);
  // ...
endmodule

interface adderSubtractor_if(
  input bit clk,
  input [7:0] a,
  input [7:0] b,
  input       doAdd,
  input [8:0] result
);
  // ...
endinterface: adderSubtractor_if

// BIND STATEMENT(S) HERE

// The test that will be run on the DUT
program automatic test(adderSubtractor_if addSub);
  initial begin
    // do stuff with interface
  end
endprogram // test

// The top level testbench.
module testbench;
  reg clk;
  adderSubtractor2 dut(.clk (clk));
  test test0(dut.adderSubtractor_if0);
`ifdef HAS_UNIT_2
  test test1(dut.adderSubtractor_if1);
`endif

  // ...
endmodule // testbench
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do. You defined an interface, but you do not use it at all. Are you asking about interfaces usage, or how can you instantiate variable number of interfaces to your module?

Comment: I added additional lines to the example above to show how the interface will be hooked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is parametrizable interface.

In general, masking ports with `ifdef is very risky, and you must have very good reasons to do this. There has already been a discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642375/systemverilog-when-to-use-define-macro-vs-generate/17113650#17113650).

I don't see any reason to use `ifdef in your case. You can:

1. define a parameter NUM_OF_INSTANCES
2. define all (except clk and rst) the ports of your module as packed arrays. i.e.

   input [1:NUM_OF_INSTANCES][7:0] a;
3. use "generate for" statement inside the module to instantiate multiple adders
4. Use parametrizable interface and bind it to the ports of the module in the usual way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case the adderSubtractor2 module ports and all the code inside that module is fixed -- code comes from another team and they won't change it. What are my choices from a verification perspective?

Comment: Shoot the designer who wrote the code.
If this is the case, I'd suggest that you add separate bindings for each sub-module (under \`ifdef of course). The code with macros that you wrote (even if it works) looks bizarre, and people that will look at your code in future will suffer. 
You're going to suffer anyway - you'll have to add these \`ifdefs in each place in your code. This is very poor design and if it can't be changed - the validation code will be poor as well.
I can think of few other options involving converting defines into parameters, but they're also ugly and may not work.

Comment: BTW, do you mind if I add a link to this page to the discussion of \`ifdefs versus generates? I think this example shows a great abuse of \`ifdefs.

Comment: Sure, add on :). Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros:

```
`define BIND_ADD_SUB(INDEX) \
bind adderSubtractor2 adderSubtractor_if adderSubtractor_if``INDEX``( \
  .clk(clk), \
  .a(a``INDEX``), \
  .b(b``INDEX``), \
  .doAdd(doAdd``INDEX``), \
  .result(result``INDEX``) \
); \

`BIND_ADD_SUB(0)
`ifdef HAS_UNIT_2
`BIND_ADD_SUB(1)
`endif
```

Then pass `dut.adderSubtractor_if0` and `dut.adderSubtractor_if1` to your testbench.